# Adding scale to partical filter

Tags: c++, opencv

The following code is for partical filter for mouse and I change it for track on video with color, this works.

But I want to add scale to it now which only works with x and y. I tried to add scale to it but I failed. Please help me to add scale to the object detected to partical filter.

```
// Module "core"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include < opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
// Module "highgui"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
// Module "imgproc"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/videostab/videostab.hpp"

// Module "video"
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>

// Output
#include <iostream>



// Vector
#include <vector>

#define drawCross( center, color, d )                  \
  line( frame, cv::Point( center.x - d, center.y - d ),           \
    cv::Point( center.x + d, center.y + d ), color, 1, CV_AA, 0);   \
  line( frame, cv::Point( center.x + d, center.y - d ),           \
    cv::Point( center.x - d, center.y + d ), color, 1, CV_AA, 0 )

#define PLOT_PARTICLES 1
using namespace std;

using namespace cv;
// >>>>> Color to be tracked
#define MIN_H_BLUE 200
#define MAX_H_BLUE 300
// <<<<< Color to be tracked
vector<cv::Point> mouseV, particleV;

int main()
{
    // Camera frame
  cv::Mat frame;
  char code = (char)-1;
  cv::namedWindow("mouse particle");
  cv::Mat_<float> measurement(2,1); 
  measurement.setTo(cv::Scalar(0));

  int dim = 2;
  int nParticles = 300;
  float xRange = 650.0;
  float yRange = 650.0;

  float minRange[] = { 0, 0 };
  float maxRange[] = { xRange, yRange };
  CvMat LB, UB;
  cvInitMatHeader(&LB, 2, 1, CV_32FC1, minRange);
  cvInitMatHeader(&UB, 2, 1, CV_32FC1, maxRange);

  CvConDensation* condens = cvCreateConDensation(dim, dim, nParticles);

  cvConDensInitSampleSet(condens, &LB, &UB);


  condens->DynamMatr[0] = 1.0;
  condens->DynamMatr[1] = 0.0;
  condens->DynamMatr[2] = 0.0;
  condens->DynamMatr[3] = 1.0;


    // Camera Index
    string idx = "a.mp4";

    // Camera Capture
    cv::VideoCapture cap;

    // >>>>> Camera Settings
    if (!cap.open(idx))
    {
        cout << "Webcam not connected.\n" << "Please verify\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1024);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 768);
    // <<<<< Camera Settings

    cout << "\nHit 'q' to exit...\n";

    char ch = 0;

    double ticks = 0;
    bool found = false;

    int notFoundCount = 0;



    // >>>>> Main loop
    while (ch != 'q' && ch != 'Q')
    {
        double precTick = ticks;
        ticks = (double) cv::getTickCount();

        double dT = (ticks - precTick) / cv::getTickFrequency(); //seconds

        // Frame acquisition
        cap >> frame;


    mouseV.clear();
    particleV.clear();


        // >>>>> Noise smoothing
        cv::Mat blur;
        cv::GaussianBlur(frame, blur, cv::Size(5, 5), 3.0, 3.0);
        // <<<<< Noise smoothing

        // >>>>> HSV conversion
        cv::Mat frmHsv;
        cv::cvtColor(blur, frmHsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        // <<<<< HSV conversion

        // >>>>> Color Thresholding
        // Note: change parameters for different colors
        cv::Mat rangeRes = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_8UC1);
        cv::inRange(frmHsv, cv::Scalar(MIN_H_BLUE / 2, 100, 80),
                    cv::Scalar(MAX_H_BLUE / 2, 255, 255), rangeRes);
        // <<<<< Color Thresholding

        // >>>>> Improving the result
        cv::erode(rangeRes, rangeRes, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
        cv::dilate(rangeRes, rangeRes, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
        // <<<<< Improving the result





         // >>>>> Contours detection
        vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
        cv::findContours(rangeRes, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,
                         CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        // <<<<< Contours detection

        // >>>>> Filtering

        vector<vector<cv::Point> > balls;
        vector<cv::Rect> ballsBox;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::Rect bBox;
            bBox = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);

            float ratio = (float) bBox.width / (float) bBox.height;
            if (ratio > 1.0f)
                ratio = 1.0f / ratio;

            // Searching for a bBox almost square
           // if (ratio > 0.55 && bBox.area() >= 50)
           // {
                 balls.push_back(contours[i]);
                 ballsBox.push_back(bBox);
                 measurement(0) = bBox.x;
                 measurement(1) = bBox.y;
                 measurement(2) = ballsBox.size();
                 //cout << "Balls found:" << bBox.x << endl;
          //  }
        }

        /*
        cout << "Balls found:" << ballsBox.size() << endl;
        */



      cv::Point measPt(measurement(0),measurement(1));
      mouseV.push_back(measPt);



      for (int i = 0; i < condens->SamplesNum; i++) {

    float diffX = (measurement(0) - condens->flSamples[i][0])/xRange;
    float diffY = (measurement(1) - condens->flSamples[i][1])/yRange;

    condens->flConfidence[i] = 1.0 / (sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY));

    // plot particles
#ifdef PLOT_PARTICLES
    cv::Point partPt(condens->flSamples[i][0], condens->flSamples[i][1]);
     drawCross(partPt , cv::Scalar(255,0,255), 2);
#endif

      }



      cvConDensUpdateByTime(condens);

      cv::Point statePt(condens->State[0], condens->State[1]);
      particleV.push_back(statePt);

        for (int i = 0; i < particleV.size() - 1; i++) {
    line(frame, particleV[i], particleV[i+1], cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 1);
      }

     drawCross( statePt, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), 5 );
      drawCross( measPt, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 5 );

        for (size_t i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::drawContours(frame, balls, i, CV_RGB(20,150,20), 1);
            cv::rectangle(frame, ballsBox[i], CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2);

            cv::Point center;
            center.x = ballsBox[i].x + ballsBox[i].width / 2;
            center.y = ballsBox[i].y + ballsBox[i].height / 2;
            cv::circle(frame, center, 2, CV_RGB(20,150,20), -1);

            stringstream sstr;
            sstr << "(" << center.x << "," << center.y << ")";
            cv::putText(frame, sstr.str(),
                        cv::Point(center.x + 3, center.y - 3),
                        cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, CV_RGB(20,150,20), 2);
        }

      cv::imshow("mouse particle", frame);
      cv::imshow("ssssssss", rangeRes);



        ch = cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    // <<<<< Main loop

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: sidenote: the condensation code from legacy is unstable, and was removed in current 3.0. rather use a KalmanFilter instead.

Comment: i have it >> just here help me to add scale and i will use it in KalmanFilter  also and maby use KalmanFilter  only